# Is there a way to limit the data being read when joining tables in spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read the data in spark sql by joining two very large tables. But i just need a fix number (let's say 500) from the resultant dataframe.
For example -

```
SELECT id, name, employee.deptno, deptname
FROM employee INNER JOIN department ON employee.deptno = department.deptno
```

Here i can use head(500) or limit(500) function on the resultant dataframe to limit the rows from resultant dataframe, But still it is going to read full data from both of the tables first and then on the resultant dataframe it will apply the limit.
Is there a way in which i can avoid reading full data before applying the limit ?

Comment: You can limit the no of records from each table using individual subqueries first and then join.

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola but i don't necessarily know the input tables in advance. This could be a very complex sql joining a number of tables which is received to me as it is. Now to extract the tables joined i will have to extract what all tables are used in this, then again create a temp table on that and then run the query on it, which will be complex.

Comment: Limit get first n lines from the query output. Your comment answers your question. Since you cannot limit the data in the underlying table and also there's no way you can know what data you need you can't achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Yes  that's correct. I have now done something like this only. Extracting individual tables first and then limiting the data on individual tables first and then joining them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
employee = spark.sql('select id, name, deptno from employee limit 500')
department = spark.sql('select deptno, deptname from department limit 500')
employee = employee.join(department, on = 'deptno', how = 'inner')
```

Comment: finally i did pretty much like this only. I guess there is no other way to do this without first extracting all the tables from the sql and then joining them on limited data.